# Overriding referenced style attributes

Tags: android, styles, themes, overriding, checkedtextview

After reading through [References To Theme Attributes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes) I am trying to reference the value of an attribute in the my custom theme that I have set.

I am applying a user-defined style to a `CheckedTextView`

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/contactInfo"
    style="@style/ListViewCheckedTextViewRowStyle" >
</CheckedTextView>
```

The user-defined style is defined as :

```
<style name="ListViewCheckedTextViewRowStyle" parent="@style/ListViewRowStyle">
    <item name="android:checkMark">?android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple</item>
</style>
```

My theme I created is defined as :

```
<style name="Theme.Yellowgreen" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/btn_check_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

However, the checkMark styling that gets displayed is the device's default theme's drawable and not my user defined drawable.

The only way I can have my drawable displayed is with :

```
<style name="ListViewCheckedTextViewRowStyle" parent="@style/ListViewRowStyle">
    <item name="android:checkMark">@drawable/btn_check_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

But that defeats the whole purpose of overriding this attribute, especially since I would like to override this attribute in multiple themes.

I am setting the theme in the `onCreate()` method of my `Activity` like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Yellowgreen);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
}
```

I also tried to set the theme in the AndroidManifest.xml file like :

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.Yellowgreen" >
```

But that didn't work.  What could be going wrong?

## Update

I just created a small sample project and it looks like the code i posted above is working.  So i must have some other styles which are overriding this property or perhaps it has to do with my layout xml files.

In my large project, I have two `Fragments` within an `Activity`.  Both `Fragments` have `Listviews` backed by `Adapters`.  In `Fragment A` the `getView()` method of the `Adapter` is as follows:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_entry, null);
    }

    //...

    return convertView;
}
```

In `Fragment B` the `getView()` method of the `Adapter` is as follows:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    //...

    return convertView;
}
```

The layouts are defined as follows:

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    
    <include layout="@layout/list_item_header" />
    
    <include layout="@layout/contact_entry" />

    <View android:id="@+id/list_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/header_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dip"
    android:background="@color/dark_blue"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**contact_entry.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contactEntry"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <QuickContactBadge
        android:id="@+id/contactPic"
        style="@style/ContactPicStyle" />

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/contactInfo"
        style="@style/ListViewCheckedTextViewRowStyle" >
    </CheckedTextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

For some reason, in `Fragment B` the themed checkMark attribute is not rendering correctly whereas in `Fragment A`, the checkMark uses the current YellowGreen Theme and is styled correctly.  Why would this be happening?

Comment: Have you specified your _YellowGreen_ theme in the manifest?

Comment: I've just created a sample project to test your style files and everything works fine for me. So I second _dominus'_ question: have you set activity theme to `YellowGreen` in the manifest?

Comment: hey @dominus and @Idolon, I updated the question.  I tried setting the activity theme two different ways but have been unsuccessful in overriding the `android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple` style attribute.

Comment: If your theme name is `YellowGreen` why did you put in manifest `@style/Theme.Yellowgreen`. I don't have much knowledge about customized themes, just trying to figure out.

Comment: @GokhanArik, I corrected the theme name.  That was a typo in the original post.

Comment: Try calling `setTheme` after `onCreate`. Otherwise I have no idea, I can't say anything before seeing your all code.

Comment: I have simplified my theme in the example i have provided in this post by excluding other attributes of the theme, but other attributes are being set properly, although they are not attributes that are being overridden.

Comment: What is `ListViewRowStyle`? Also, this happens on one API level or it's a general behavior?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you need that line in your theme

```
<item name="android:checkedTextViewStyle">@style/ListViewCheckedTextViewRowStyle</item>
```

so it would look like this:

```
<style name="Theme.Yellowgreen" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/btn_check_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:checkedTextViewStyle">@style/ListViewCheckedTextViewRowStyle</item>
</style>
```

**UPDATE**

After question update and some additional information form comments we found that the problem was in `Context`. It's the same mistake I did in that my question: [Android color selector doesn't work with custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005015/android-color-selector-doesnt-work-with-custom-attributes)

To one fragment was passed `Activity` and to the other `Application`. I'm not an expert but even both of those classes are extending `Context` only the `Activity` extends `ContextThemeWrapper`, which has information about styles. It might be helpful to read that article for future understanding Context: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/

Comment: Hey @Mikoos, I just tried adding this attribute to my theme but unfortunately it doesn't override the attribute `android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple`.

Comment: It might be easier if you give us whole sample project on github with comments what exactly are you want to achieve. Solution could be given using poll request.

Comment: Thanks @Mikoos, I have posted more of my project's code and believe I am getting closer to finding out what's wrong.  Hopefully I have provided enough details.

Comment: What is the context of mInflater? If you passed context to Adapter using context.getApplicationContext() it wont style it properly. You need to pass Activities context.

Comment: Thanks @Mikoos.  I unintentionally was passing the context.getApplicationContext() to `Fragment B`, I fixed this and it is finally styled correctly.  Can you please update your answer and make a note about why you must pass Activity Context instead of Application Context and I will accept your answer and reward you the bounty.

Comment: Thanks again @Mikoos, that article explains everything.