# Create android selector extending background ?attr/selectableItemBackground?

Tags: android, button, drawable

I want to create a button background, which is exactly the same as ?attr/selectableItemBackground but with a black stroke outline.

Is there a way to "extend" ?attr/selectableItemBackground and add a black outline or will I have to create a completely new stateList?

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103894/overriding-referenced-style-attributes

Comment: no exactly the same issue.