# I am using this layout and want to change the color of text and checkbox to white

Tags: java, android

I am using this layout and want to change the color of text and checkbox to white, I tried to add property 'android:textcolor' but there was no change

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd" />
```

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103894/overriding-referenced-style-attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by copying and pasting the code to a new xml file. As the previous xml file in which i was trying to add the color was locked and wasn't allowing me to modify it contents.

Answer (score 0):

`android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textColor="@color/white"`

should be working formats white coloring. Tested on my machine and it works fine.

seems like you may have forgotten to capitalize the C in `android:textColor`